# Why isn't the redirect in the container working and an error is trown?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redirect

Upon clicking the button, the page fails to redirect to the 'list-todos' page, instead triggering a 403 error

Controller:
`@RequestMapping(value = "add-todo", method = RequestMethod.POST)   public String addNewTodo() {        return "redirect:list-todos";   }`

View:
`

```
<form method="post">

    <fieldset class="mb-3">
        <label>Description</label> 
        <input type="text" name="decription" /> 
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset class="mb-3">
        <label>Target Date</label> 
        <input type="text" name="targetDate" />
    </fieldset>
    
    <input type="hidden" name="id" />
    
    <input type="hidden" name="done" />
    
    
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" />

</form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="webjars/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

`

Error:
`Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Mar 12 17:37:58 CET 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Forbidden`

P.S.: I use Spring Security

I stored The User in a session

`@Controller @SessionAttributes("name")`